# Como alterar o tamanho mínimo requerido para o password

Tags: laravel

Estou tentando alterar o tamanho mínimo para o campo 'password' mas não encontro.

Alguém sabe informar qual a quantidade mínima que o Laravel requer para este campo e se é possível alterar? Em caso positivo, onde posso fazer essa alteração?

Comment: Qual a versão Walder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para alterar o tamanho mínimo, faça assim em sua variável de validação:

```
'password' => 'required|min:8'
```

Mais detalhes você pode conferir na **[documentação](http://laravel.com/docs/validation)**.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, Paulo.